# Get all list of specified site from SharePoint OnLine (trial)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I want to get all the `List` of specified `Site` from SharePoint OnLine by `RESTful API`. The `URL` I used is `Https://mySiteUrl/_api/web/lists`. But Why the result contains the `Document Libaray` item(I added it for test)? And another question why the items shows  in the web page is 12. But the result is 24 ? What exactly return of `_api/web/lists`? Thanks.

All `Site Collections` can be seen in my the `SharePoint Online`(Trial version).

[image]

All site content can be seen for the specified site.

[image]

The query result of JSON.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '*_api/web/lists*' will return all the 'Lists' in a SharePoint Site. In SharePoint, a 'Document Library' is considered a type of List, that's why it's showing up in your results.

Comment: oh .. So How to identify `List` or `Document Library` from the result ? And What about my second question. Why the result count is 24? Thanks.

Comment: The third property listed in the JSON Viewer application "Base Template" is what you can use to identify the List Type. A standard list is '100', a Document Library is '101'. Here's a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype(v=office.15).aspx


  The reason there are 24 results is because some lists are hidden from the user interface, that's the "Hidden" Property in your JSON Viewer.